# Why is the gain of this LC two-port network infinite?

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, gain, band-pass

Consider the following two port network, where a voltage is measured across the output terminals (no current), and the input is connected to an AC power source:

[image]

Calculating the voltage gain of this circuit using the impedance divider rule for series components gives:

\begin{align}
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}&=\frac{Z_C}{Z_C+Z_L}\\
&=\frac{j\omega L}{j\omega L + \frac1{j\omega C}}\\
&=\frac{j\omega L}{j\omega L - \frac{j}{\omega C}}\\
&=\frac{\omega L}{\omega L - \frac1{\omega C}}\\
&=\frac1{1 - \frac1{\omega^2 LC}}
\end{align}

Clearly when 
$$\omega=\frac1{\sqrt{LC}}$$
then division by zero will occur and the gain will be undefined. Assuming I haven't made any mistakes in calculating the voltage gain, could you please explain to me how this can make physical sense. What would happen in real life if I chose all of the values so that division by zero occurred?

Apparently the value for the angular frequency shown above is the resonance frequency for series LC circuits. Is the following answer (my guess) correct: "The gain is 'infinite' because the circuit shown above has no resistance, so more and more energy is inserted into the circuit, as it resonates, building up energy, forever. In a real circuit, the gain would not be infinite, due to losses in the circuit."

**EDIT:** I recalculated, incorporating a resistor in series, and the gain function changed as shown below (no resistance in red and with resistance in purple). The graph shown is with R = C = L = 1, it just gives you an idea of the shape.

[image]

Comment: Reality impinges. A frequency won't exist from \$t=-\infty\$ to \$t=\infty\$. It exists for a limited duration. Circuits exist for a limited time. And all circuits have parasitics such as resistance. As an aside, compute the new resonant frequency where the capacitor and inductor both have realistic series resistances added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gain is theoretically infinite, but even in theory it would take an infinite time to see the output reach an infinite amplitude.

In physical practice, there will be always be losses, which will limit the gain, even with a super-conducting L and a high quality vacuum capacitor.

Even in the absence of losses, each of the components will have a maximum limit.

As the energy in the circuit builds up, the current increases in the circuit. The power supply will need to support that current, no power supply can deliver an infinite load current. The wires connecting the components will melt at some finite current.

If the inductor is made on a core of iron or ferrite, then as the current builds, it will saturate, changing the L and detuning the resonance.

If you flip the L and C around, you have the business end of a 'magnifier' Tesla coil. When the energy in the capacitor, that is the voltage on it, gets high enough, pretty sparks break out from it. Any capacitor will have a maximum withstand voltage. No capacitor, unless it is has an infinite distance between its plates (that is, no real capacitor), can stand an infinite voltage.

Comment: Would building such a circuit be dangerous? Leaving it until Vout reached dangerous levels?

Comment: @hddh It depends how you define 'dangerous'. Dangerous with an AA battery might be only interesting, whereas dangerous with mains might burn your house down. I did do a thought experiment for using chokes and capacitors from flourescent lamps to build precisely your circuit, but even though I've decided that inductor saturation will detune the resonance to stop the buildup of energy at some point, I've not progressed to building it, because, well, the thought experiment is enough for me. Look for Tesla coil videos on youtube to see what 'safe dangerous' output capacitor breakover looks like.